# Angularjs avoid $emit and share a variable across directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-service

I have a situtation where in i want to avoid using $emit to share a scope variable and instead share some property using a underlying service, the problem is that the property value gets set on return of a promise response in directive 1 and by the time that property value is set in service through directive 1, directive 2 is already loaded and hence the property comes as undefined in directive 2.
Any ideas?

Comment: you really should set up a plunker, or at least share some code.  or both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the provided information, thought of writing this code fragment. Hope this will give you some insights to find the best answer.

```
angular.module('myApp').service('SomeService', function($http) {

    this.readData = function(dataUrl) {
        // read data;
        return $http.get(dataUrl)
            .then(function(res) {
                return res.data;
            }, function(res) {
                return res;
            }
    }

    return this;
});

angular.module('myApp').controller('MyController', function($scope, SomeService) {
    $scope.readData = function(url) {
        SomeService.readData(url)
        .then(function(res) {
            $scope.data = res;
        }, function(res) {
            // Display error
        }
    }

}

angular.module('myApp').directory('myDirectory1', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {
            scope.data = scope.readData(url);
        }
    }
});

angular.module('myApp').directory('myDirectory2', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            data : '@'
        },
        link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {
            scope.$watch('data', function(newVal) {
                // Do some stuffs
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps extract the functionality that delivers the promise from your directive1 to the service, and in both directives use

```
.then(function(data){ ... } )
```